# Fill div background with responsive image

Tags: html, reactjs, css

I am trying to place an image as background of div and have the image resized when window size is changing.

React component:

```
import React from 'react';

const Test = () => {
  return (
   <div className="img-fluid test">
    <br/> // if I add this tag then part of the image is shown
    <br/> // if I add another one, then image is shown even more! still not entire 
   </div>
  )
}

export default Test;
```

Route:

```
<Route path="/test" exact component={Test}/>
```

Css:

```
.test {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background: url('/images/1.jpg') no-repeat;
}
```

When I visit http://localhost:3000/test nothing is shown. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: instead of background, have you tried -> background-image: url('/images/1.jpg') no-repeat;

Comment: yes. and it doesn't show anything at all

Comment: Is your image directory inside the CSS directory? If is not and it is in the parent the you should do url('../images/1.jpg')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this...

```
background-image: url('/images/1.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
height: 100vh;
width: 100%;
```

You need to give it an explicit height and width as well.  Auto will NOT work. 10em is just for the example so set it to whatever you need the div to be.  Background images don't stretch out the div to fit their size.

Comment: Can you check your network tab in developer tools and confirm that the image is being downloaded correctly.

Comment: Realized you never set a height and width for the div.  I edited my answer.  You can remove the break tags now.  If that still doesn't work make sure the image is loading properly through from the Network.

Comment: Did I answer your question?

Comment: partly. Now only 10 em of the image is loaded and not the entire. What I want to do is display the entire image and make it responsive as well. would that be possible?

Comment: Can you post an example of what you are trying to accomplish?  'show the whole image' is kind of ambiguous as is 'making it responsive'.  I also updated my answer again.   Try that out.  Mess with the background-position and size properties to suit your needs.